# How can I execute multiple bq commands for different projects using gcloud configurations

Tags: google-bigquery, gcloud

On my linux server, I have a 'load_app' user account. My plan was to write a generic shell script to load data into bigquery using bq tool. gcloud is installed and I have multiple configurations in my environment. These configurations point to different service and user accounts for different projects. I am trying to set it up such that I can run multiple executions of this script at the same time for different configurations.

I tried setting CLOUDSDK_ACTIVE_CONFIG_NAME= in my script, the config-name value is being passed to the script. This setting should switch the active configuration, however, I am getting the following error :
ERROR: (bq) There was a problem refreshing your current auth tokens: invalid_grant: Bad Request

Comment: have you tried some thing like opening different shell sessions               
$ # Shell 1
$ export CLOUDSDK_ACTIVE_CONFIG_NAME=config1
$ gcloud # ...
$ # Shell 2
$ export CLOUDSDK_ACTIVE_CONFIG_NAME=config2
$ gsutil # ...

Comment: project A and project B. Create a service account in project A you should go to project B to "IAM". There you will be able to add the email you just created with appropiate roles... then when running bq command add --project_id and --service_account flags

Comment: The suggestion from @PaddyPopeye would be the best approach. It is not recommended to use User/Personal accounts for this kind of automation. The error you are getting seems to be related to this as well. Do you have the same issue if you switch between service accounts configurations?